# Is there any tool to strip out CSS from media queries and perhaps output them separately?

Tags: css

Is there any tool to strip out CSS from media queries and output them separately?

That way, it is easier to create several different stylesheets for different media queries. Also can be used for mobile-first CSS to strip desktop styles for earlier browsers such as IE8 (which is what I'm trying to do.)

Let's say I have a large CSS file with different media queries. I ONLY want the styles inside the different media queries and since it is large, I want a tool that automatically does that.

It could be any tool as long as it accepts:

- a CSS input. Either uploading a file or pasting the contents works.

And outputs:

- multiple CSS outputs, each containing styles from every media query (preferably grouped if there are multiple of the same query.) File downloads or outputs work.

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: If possible, any. I am currently using Windows but I hope it won't matter that much...